# Drush not working

Tags: drush

I am using Drush 7 version on my MAC with MAMP PRO. When I am using any command of Drush it shows me an error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Users/pankajsachdeva/drush/includes/preflight.inc on line 49

Can anybody help me to get out of it?

Comment: Yep, you need to increase your PHP memory limit to something above 256kb

Comment: @Clive, I already set it to 512MB.

Comment: PHP disagrees @Pankaj - either you have a bugged version of PHP, or you've set it in the wrong place. PHP CLI has a 262,144 byte memory limit according to the error message

Comment: Have you restarted MAMP after making the change?

Comment: @Leigh Mason, yes restarted it.

Comment: @kenorb No, it's not the duplicate of WSOD, since the problem here is about Drush not Drupal, and it is not on a browser but on command line. On a command line it is not possible to get a white screen of death, is it?

Comment: Although the error and answer is the same, to increase `memory_limit`.

Comment: No, the answer is not exactly the same, since the php.ini file is different and this is an important difference!

Answer (score 1):

Drush uses the CLI version of PHP, which has its own `php.ini` file. You should locate this `php.ini` file on your installation and increase the memory limit. It can be on different places depending on how you installed the PHP.

It is generally around the same folder with the regular `php.ini` file but has something with `cli`.

For example on my Linux machine, the regular `php.ini` file is located under

> /etc/php5/**apache2**/php.ini

And the **CLI-Version** is located under:

> /etc/php5/**cli**/php.ini